# Rest API - To list all tickets created on Jira Service Desk from Python

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

I have a requirement to list all tickets created on **Jira Service desk** through Rest API from **Python**.

Can any one help me sharing API URL to list all Jira Service desk Tickets all list.

Currently i am aware of following API to list details of a particular Tickets :-

```
https://jira.mycom.com/rest/api/latest/issue/{ticket-id}?expand=names,renderedFields
```

please suggest

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with Microsoft Unified Service Desk for Dynamics 365. Please revise the tags. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified answer for my questions.
To Connect Jira Service desk, we should use following Jira Service Desk Rest API to pull all tickets associated with that Jira Service Desk Projects.

Rest API -

```
https://jira.digital.ingka.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%3D%22{Project-Id}%22
```